# Updating Linux Server from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: ubuntu

I have three VPS Linux machines running on Ubuntu 13.10 (with Nginx1.6).
I want (need) to upgrade to ubuntu 14.4 for several reasons.
On these servers I have company software running like JIRA, GITLAB, DOKUWIKI and DoveCot mailserver.

Can I just update from 13 to 14 without any (failure) risks,
or do I need to prepare myself for all kinds of conflict errors after the upgrade?

I have read 14.04 changelog, but I only see the new features instead of expected errors and conflicts..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migration between two major distribution versions are always risky. Particularly if there are some software with custom configurations.

Could you make a clone of at least one of your servers and migrate it to identify where the migration doesn't work "out of the box" ?

Comment: I can make a 'snapshot' and put it on another server to test it first, but all three servers have different functionality. 1) Running Jira, Wiki & GitLab. 2) DEVelopment (test)server and 3) running mail and ispconfig. So that means I would have to do the 'snapshot-test' 3 times..   QUESTION: What is the (security)risk if I just keep them running under the currently installed Ubuntu 13.10? (Even do it's not suported anymore)..

Comment: @JohnDoe: The answer is in your question. As 13.10 is not supported anymore you won't get any security updates from Ubuntu, you need to ensure the security yourself.

Comment: Sounds obvious, of course.. :P   Well, in the meantime I took the jump and upgraded Server #3 to 14.10. All is running without any problems. Just reconfiguring NGinX and phpMyAdmin as those configurations could be improved. So, I think I will try the other server too.. (any time soon).. Thanks for the quick and helpfull responses!!